# Using command/macro as an optional argument

Tags: macros

I have a bunch of images to include and want to use the same clip parameters on them. The approach I'm taking doesn't seem to work though:

This works:

```
\includegraphics[clip,trim=0 0 80px 80px, width=\x\textwidth]{image}
```

This doesn't:

```
\newcommand\x{.22}
\newcommand\mytrim{0 0 80px 80px}
\includegraphics[clip,trim=\mytrim, width=\x\textwidth]{image}
                            ^              ^- Does work
                            ^- Doesn't work
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about `\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\mytrim}{\includegraphics[clip, trim=}, width=\x\textwidth]{image}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax `0.5\textwidth`  is built in to tex so a length setting of `\x\textwidth` where `\x` is a factor such as `0.5` just works naturally, however the macros behind `trim` key needs to parse the space separated list "by hand" and `\mytrim` doesn't have any spaces until it is expanded.

Comment: So is there any alternative? Or is there no way around copy/paste in this instance?

Comment: @argentum2f oh lots of things you could do but you provided very little context and no test file, you could do `\newcommand\zz[1]{\includegraphics[clip,trim=0 0 80px 80px, width=.22\textwidth]{#1}` for example then `\zz{image1}  \zz{image2}`